# Posting NSNotification when receiving Push crash

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

When I receive a push notification, I postNotificaionName via NSNotificationCenter (from the AppDelegate method below):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

  playSoundWithUserInfo(userInfo)
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotifPushReceived, object: nil)

}
```

I am making one of my view-controllers an observer for this notification:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(retrieveUsersAndSetData(_:)), name: kNotifPushReceived, object: nil
}

func retrieveUsersAndSetData(completed : (() -> Void)?) {
    Friendship.retrieveFriendshipsForUser(backendless.userService.currentUser, includeGroups: false) { (friendships, fault) -> Void in
    guard let friendships = friendships else { return }
    self.friendships = friendships
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Most of the time I receive a push notification, I receive a crash in the appDelegate where postNotificationName() is called:

[image]

The crash reads:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10070)

Now most answers I've read that seem similar to this problem suggest that an object who was made an observer was never properly released, however I do not believe that is the case here because this is currently the only view-controller in the app, and I am implementing the following from the view-controller who is the observer of the notification:

```
  deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
  }
```

All in all, I cannot figure out why this crash occurs most of the time when I receive the push notification in the app delegate and then post my NSNotification.

Comment: only thing I can point at is kNotifPushReceived might be nil.

Comment: @GauravPal it definitely has a string value. I've since put the code that was inside the closure of my observer's selector on the main thread and it seems to be stable so far

Answer (score 0):

The handler method 'fetchCompletionHandler' expects by you to call the completionHandler at the end of your processing:

```
 completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
```

Please read the documentation of this method, there is more to consider then just that.

Comment: Yes, I had  completionHandler(.NewData)  at the end of the didReceiveRemoteNotification: method; forget to include in my example code. However, I had the same issue regardless. As I mentioned in a comment on my post, this crash disappeared when I dispatched the code of my observer's selector to the main thread.

Comment: So everythinh fine now? If yes then answer your own question and accept the answe with your own solution. So others can find it also.